# javax.inject.Inject beans not recognized in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cdi

I have an external dependency (added as dependency in pom.xml) which uses dependency injection using CDI `(javax.inject.Inject)` in my spring boot app. I'm trying to `Autowired` one those CDI managed bean but had no luck.

I keep getting below error.

`No qualifying bean of type '<Bean name>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

I tried `ComponentScan` to scan the CDI managed bean but it doesn't help either.

Could someone help on how to get Spring boot aware of the CDI managed beans

Comment: A CDI bean is not a Spring bean, since it's not annotated with `@Component` (or any other Spring component annotation). If you want it to be a Spring bean, you need to explicitly create a bean of this type. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts

Comment: @JBNizet Is it possible using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`as Spring documentation states so. Please check  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-instantiating-container

Comment: Spring will honor the Inject annotation inside the classes, but you still need to make them Spring beans. Spring doesn't create a bean just because it finds a field or method annotated with Inject.

Comment: @JBNizet It is an external dependency and I can't make any modification with that to make them Spring beans. Is there any other options left for me?

Comment: Sure: read my first comment, where I link to the documentation explaining how to create a Spring bean, even for a class you can't change. You need to **click** on the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your bean that Spring manages.

In Java code you could do this (notice this works for any class, even if it's from a 3rd party library you don't control):

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        // Return a new instance of your class here
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

Or in XML:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="myBean" class="abc.def.MyBean"/>
</beans>
```

Now you can inject `MyBean` using either `@Inject` or Spring's `@Autowired` annotation.